# Can I scale web apps in Azure to more than 20 instances?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-web-app-service

For example, I have one web app, which I can scale by CPU percentage up to 20 instances. But for me do 20 instances is not enough. Can I create autoscale rules to scale web apps to more instances than that? Is that possible?

Comment: is this a WebApp or Web Role?

Answer (score 2):

The default instances limit is set to prevent people making costly mistakes.  Contact Azure support to get a higher limit.

Comment: were you able to do this by contacting MS?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum you can use in a single multi tenant App Service Plan is 20 instances, if you want more for your App Service Plan you may look into App Service Environments:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-intro/

Other option is to clone your web app a number of times (across regions or within the same region), you can use the recently announced cloning feature:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-app-cloning/